# Recommendations for music games for children

Tags: software-recommendation, games

Can anyone recommend some good music games for small children? I thought something like a virtual piano or drum, but with a very simple GUI. My girls are three and six, and they already love to play tuxpaint, I am looking for something similar for music.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good children orientated distro is [doudoulinux](http://www.doudoulinux.org).

One of there recommended young children applications is a virtual keyboard such as this:

[image]

You can play this virtual keyboard with the keys of your computer.

Similarly - but I think better is Drumstick Virtual Keyboard (from the software center) which you can easily make a full screen keyboard by double clicking the title bar.

[image]

### DrumStick Piano Keyboard

Install the following software packages from the Software Center:

- DrumStick Piano Keyboard
- timidity

Run DrumStick and connect to timidity by the menu option "Edit - Output Tab - Timidity:0"

### Virtual Keyboard ## .

Install the following software packages from the Software Center:

- Virtual Midi Keyboard
- aconnect
- timidity

To connect the virtual keyboard to play sounds via the timidity synth:

```
timidity &
```

run the virtual Midi Keyboard app

```
vkeyd &
```

and then connect the two pieces of software together

```
aconnect 129 128
```

Obviously you could script this together to run from a desktop icon.

Comment: I tried out DrumStick Piano - my six year old loves it. I also installed DrumStick Drum Grid, she is having a lot of fun. I have seen Doudoulinux before, I think I am going to put it on an old PC for the kids.

Answer (score 7):

Probably a bit too much for a 3 year old but your 6 year old might like [Frets on fire](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fretsonfire) [image: Install fretsonfire]!

A game of musical skill and fast fingers. The aim of the game is to play guitar with the keyboard as accurately as possible.

Players must press buttons to keep in time with the rhythm of the music, shown by markers on screen. An official online high score list allows players to show off their skills to competitors around the globe.

The game comes with an easy to understand tutorial to get players started, and a song editor lets players edit and compose songs for use in the game.

[image]

What 6 year old does not like buttonbashing? :D
You should get an old keyboard though!

Comment: Yeah, get an old keyboard or you may find that some keys don't work after :)

Comment: I actually play this myself. Good pick! And good advice about an old keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

There is a game where you mimic the notes of an alien craft.  It's called "Ninth Kind", and you can download the deb package of it here [here](https://www.pygame.org/project/1824).  There is also a game called "Simon clone" that is a much simpler version of this game.  It's deb package is found [here](https://www.pygame.org/project/3097).  And there is a little noise maker that is fun to mess around with and is also very simple called "Pitch Perfect" a deb package of it is found in the music section.

Answer (score 0):

there is a good game called Audiosurf. It can be installed via Steam. [How-to: Steam under Linux](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux)